# Array conversion

Tags: php, arrays, formatting

Array conversion

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

in formate like

```
$arry2 = array([1],[2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]);
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Your second array seems to be an array consisting of subarrays of the first array like so: 1st starting from (1-1) with length 1, 2nd starting from (2-1) and length 2, 3rd starting from (4-1) and length 3, and generally starting from (2^(k-1) - 1) with length k, or is there some more obvious logic behind this which I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to consequently get items from array as arrays of increasing length

```
$i = 1;
$arry2 = [];
while ($t = array_splice($array1, 0, $i++))
   $arry2[] = $t;
```